# Erase / Filter rows with info from the ones in blank

Tags: google-sheets, filter, flatten, blank-line, nonblank

I have this data in a Google Sheet, basically is a dynamic table that will have more information or could change in a future with more or less rows, in the same image at the right you will see what I need, I was thinking about use BLANK but is giving me some errors, also I tried with transposeFilter but same problem. Some help or recommendations please! (The only information not dynamic is the blue rows)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try for horizontal erase:

```
=FILTER(A:D; TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:D);;9^9)))<>"")
```

or vertical erase:

```
=FILTER(A:D; TRIM(QUERY(A:D;;9^9))<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks that is the solution I was looking for

Comment: I have a doubt this only works with horizontal ranges right?

Comment: @Eduardomaker yes. answer updated